# preventing Google GMail for converting a number to an anchor tel

Tags: html, css, gmail, anchor

I have noticed that emails I send from my application to GMail mail boxes are having the courier tracking number converted to a `<a href="tel:289173892173">` automatically by Google.

My markup, before it gets to Google, is:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">6367878366</span>
```

However, Google must do some sort of number length detection on the content of the span and change it automatically to an anchor.

Is there a way to prevent this in GMail?

GMail:

[image: href_tel]

Outlook:

[image]

Comment: is that realizing all other markups

Comment: try someother like div, label instead of span

Comment: GMail also does it with an `<em>`, so it would appear it's not localised to `<span>` tags.

Comment: I have also tested it with a `<div>` and it is the same, it would appear that the content is what is driving the conversion to an anchor and not a combination of the tag and content.